# Magento 2 Custom Report grid is not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

Is anyone has created custom Report grid in Magento 2 Admin panel?

We have started to create a report but we are facing an issue with display data and while we click on "Refresh" button entire page is messed up.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="reports_report_grid"/>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.report.grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">gridMaterialReport</argument>
            <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">Commercepundit\CoreAdminOrder\Model\ResourceModel\Material\Collection\Initial</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.report.grid.export">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="exportTypes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="csv" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">*/*/exportOrdersCsv</item>
                </item>
                <item name="excel" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">*/*/exportOrdersExcel</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.report.grid.columnSet">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="count_totals" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
        </arguments>
        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.report.grid.columnSet.order_id" as="order_id">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Id</argument>
                <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">order_id</argument>
                <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">order_id</argument>
                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.report.grid.columnSet.sqft" as="sqft">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sqft</argument>
                <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">number</argument>
                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">sqft</argument>
                <argument name="total" xsi:type="string">sum</argument>
                <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">sqft</argument>
                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-qty</argument>
                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-qty</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

+++++++++++++++++

[image]

While we can click on Refresh entire page is look like below.

[image]

Can anyone help me on this??

Thanks,

Comment: can you remove <arguments>
            <argument name="count_totals" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
        </arguments>

Comment: @PritamInfo24: I have resolved that issue, there was a collection issue in the Resource model I have added _joinFields and setDateRange function.
now, i am getting "ReportJsObject is not defined".

Please find link for more information:  https://prnt.sc/lrz56b

Do you have any idea??

Comment: Did you use $this->getSelect() in your collection class  to check the select query is ok or not.

Comment: Yes it's working fine.

 $this->getSelect()->addFieldToFilter(
            'created_at',
            ['from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate, 'datetime' => true]
        );

Comment: Can you try this
 $this->getSelect();
        $this->addAttributeToFilter(
            'created_at',
            ['from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate, 'datetime' => true]
        );

Comment: @PritamInfo24
We have resolved an issue. there was issue with adding filter.
now its done with:

$this->addFieldToFilter(
            'created_at',
            ['from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate, 'datetime' => true]
        );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved an issue for Report Grid.

I have added below function in the Resource model

```
/**
 * Join fields
 *
 * @param string $fromDate
 * @param string $toDate
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _joinFields($fromDate = '', $toDate = '')
{
    $this->addFieldToFilter(
        'created_at',
        ['from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate, 'datetime' => true]
    );
    //echo $this->getSelect()->__toString();
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set date range
 *
 * @param string $fromDate
 * @param string $toDate
 * @return $this
 */
public function setDateRange($fromDate, $toDate)
{
    $this->_reset()->_joinFields($fromDate, $toDate);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set store filter to collection
 *
 * @param array $storeIds
 * @return $this
 */
public function setStoreIds($storeIds)
{
    if ($storeIds) {
        $this->addFieldToFilter('store_id', ['in' => (array)$storeIds]);
    } 
    return $this;
}
```

now its working fine :)

Comment: how to use for <update handle="reports_sales"/>?

Comment: can you share the full code, i am facing the same issue. Thanks